# Evaluate the least significant decimal digit $ 109873^{7951}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to understand the below, I can t seem to see or understand, how and why and where the answers where arrived at.

Evaluate the least significant decimal digit of $ 109873^{7951}$

Solution:

We need to calculate $ 109873^{7951}$ (mod 10)

```
φ(10) = 4  // Firstly how is 4 the answer
```

$ 109873^{7951}(\mod 10) = 3^{(7951 \mod φ(10))} (\mod 10) = 3^{(7951 \mod 4)} (\mod 10) = 3^3
(\mod 10) = 7$

I am wondering if someone could explain to me also how the other answer is 7..? I would grateful if someone could step me though this.

Comment: An easier solution : Reduce the base modulo $10$ and the exponent modulo $4$ to get $3^3=27$, giving the answer $7$ faster. The reduction modulo $4$ is allowed because of $gcd(109873,10)=1$. $\phi(10)$ is the number of residue classes coprime to $10$. From the numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$, the numbers $1,3,7,9$ are coprime to $10$, so $\phi(10)=4$

Comment: "other answer"? There is only one answer and it is 7.

Comment: oh... four isn't the final answer.  4 is just the value of $\phi(10)$ = # of relative prime numbers less than 10.  As 1, 3, 7, and 9 are all the relatively prime numbers $\phi(10) = 4$.  Then use Euler's Tortient Theorem: if gcd(a, n) = 1 then $a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \mod n$ where $a = 109873$ and $n = 10$.

Comment: Essentially this same question has recurred here a number of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\varphi(10)$ is $4$ because $4$ of the numbers between 0 and 10 are coprime to 10, namely $\{1,3,7,9\}$.

We can also compute this by the rules that $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ when $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and $\varphi(p)=p-1$ when $p$ is prime, so
$$ \varphi(10)=\varphi(2)\varphi(5)=(2-1)(5-1)=1\cdot 4 = 4$$

Since $10$ is square-free, a generalization of Euler's theorem states that $a^k\equiv a^m\pmod{10}$ when $k\equiv m\pmod{\varphi(10)}$.

So since $7951\equiv 3\pmod 4$ we have
$$ 109873^{7951} \equiv 109873^3 \pmod{10} $$
And it is easy to compute the last digit of this: just ignore everything to the left of the ones column when multiplying, so the last digit of $109873^3$ is the same as the last digit of $3^3$.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is $7$.

See:
$$109873^{7951} \equiv {(10987 \cdot 10 + 3)}^{7951} \equiv 3^{7951} \pmod{10}$$

Now we use modular exponentiation.

First of all, we express the exponent in binary: $$7951_{10)} = 1111100001111_{2)}$$

So $3^{7951}$ is congruent to $\prod_{i \in A} b_i$, where $A = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12\}$.

That is, $3^{7951}$ is congruent to the product of all terms $b_j$ where $j$ are all the positions of the vector $1111100001111$ which are $1$.

So: $$b_0 = 3$$
$$b_1 = b_0^2 \equiv 9$$
$$b_2 = b_1^2 \equiv 1$$

Now we stop, because we notice that $\forall (j \geq 2)\; b_j \equiv 1$, so:

$$109873^{7951} \equiv 3^{7951} \equiv b_0 \cdot b_1 \equiv 3 \cdot 9 \equiv 27 \equiv 7\pmod{10}$$

Answer (score 0):

it's called Euler's Torient Thereom:  http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch05s02.html

If $gcd(a, n) = 1$ then $a^{\phi(n)} = 1 \mod n$ where $\phi(n)$ = number of natural numbers less than or equal to $n$ that are relatively prime to $n$.

There is another aspect:  $\phi(nm) = \phi(n)\phi(m)$.  And for $p$ prime: $\phi(p) = p - 1$.

So that's all you need to know.

$gcd(10, 109873) = 1$ so $109873^{\phi(10)} \equiv 1 \mod 10$

$\phi(10) = \phi(2)\phi(5) = 1* 4 = 4$. (The numbers 1,3,7,9 are the four numbers relatively prime to 10 BTW).  So

$109873^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$ so

$109873^{7951} = 109873^{4*something_Im_too_lazy_but_the_remainer_is_3 + 3} =$

$ (109873^4)^{something_Im_too_lazy_but_the_remainer_is_3}109873^3$

$\equiv 1^{something_Im_too_lazy_but_the_remainer_is_3}109873^3 \equiv 109873^3 \mod 10$

$\equiv (10897*10 + 3)^3 \equiv 3^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 7 \mod 10$

====

actually the very *first* thing to note is $108973^m = (10*10897 + 3)^m$ and by the binomial theorem $(10*10897 + 3)^m = 10*Ashootloadofstuffthatisamultipleoften + 3^m$ for all $m$.

So $109873^{7951} \equiv 3^{7951} \mod 10$.

$gcd(3,10) =1$ so $3^{4} \equiv 1 \mod 10$.  (Check it out: $3^4 = 81$)

So $3^{7951} = 3^{7948}3^3 = (3^4)^{1987}3^3 \equiv 3^3 \mod 10 \equiv 27 \equiv 7 \mod 10$.